# How to read the return Value return of CommandLineInterface-App?

Tags: c#, c++, command-line-interface

i hope someone can help me. I have an XML file which contains some point-coordinates and its diameters and another xml-file with some geometric data. I want to calculate if there is an intersection or clash between the spheres and the geometries.

i have written an App in C++ which calculates a clash between the sphere´s and the geometries. It works fine.
The next step is to build a GUI to manage the xmls and to add the results (if clash then write something into the point-node) to the xml-file. My idea is to do this in C# and to call the CLI-App for each sphere . After passing the arguments the App calculates the clash and returns a value (0 = clash, 1 = otherwise). How can i call the CLI-App and read the return value using C#?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you simply looking for `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`?

Comment: Consider to refactor the common part of console app (extracting methods, etc.) and future GUI app into dll.

Comment: how do i get the return value using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start?